# Sinatra, MySQL and ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, activerecord, sinatra

how do I set up a simple sinatra app to use MySQL and ActiveRecord? I found some solutions, but none of them worked (maybe they are outdated):

http://ericfarkas.com/posts/sinatra-activerecord-and-mysql/

http://labs.thredup.com/setting-up-sinatra-with-mysql-and-activerecor

So what is the best practise method, to use Sinatra along with MySQL and ActiveRecord? The https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord gem is only for sqlite3, as far as I can see.

I'm not sure if I need models or just plain SQL queries. But getting it to work all together would help me a lot.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a dead simple Sinatra-MySQL-ActiveRecord application. It has 2 files:

`Gemfile` and `app.rb`

Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra', '1.3.1'
gem 'activerecord', '3.2.13'
```

app.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "host",
  :username => "user",
  :password => "password",
  :database => "db"
)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
end

class App < Sinatra::Application
end

get '/' do
  p User.all
end
```

1. Create these 2 files
2. do `bundle install` (`gem install bundler` if you havent)
3. `ruby app.rb`

You should read how to insert data using ActiveRecord. In this case, you can manually enter some data to the table from MySQL and see the output.

Comment: `require "rubygems"` is not necessary. This is automatically included as of ruby version 1.9.x +

Comment: I've copied your sample code but I am seeing the error: in `rescue in const_missing': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter::SchemaCreation (NameError)
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `bundle install` first?

Comment: You might also need to add "gem 'mysql2'" to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [`sinatra-activerecord`](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord) gem with `MySQL` and avial other features too.

Following is the way to use it:

```
require "sinatra/activerecord"

set :database, "mysql2://#{db_username}:#{db_password}@#{db_host}:#{db_port}/#{db_database}"

# Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

get '/' do
  @items = User.all
  erb :index
end
```