# Removing default gems from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I am writing a backend server using Rails 4 that interacts with web server via database. Therefore, I don't use a lot of default gems in Rails. For example, I don't have any view or controllers.

However, I do need ActiveRecord. Therefore, I choose not to use Sinatra.

Is it possible to remove default gems from a Rails app (for example, ActiveController etc.) so that it is closer to metal? Which gems should I remove to improve performance speed?

Comment: Also, you can use ActiveRecord with Sinatra: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683903/sinatra-mysql-and-activerecord

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Rails API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) gem?  It sounds like it might fit your needs.